# How do I stream an audio file to nodejs while it's still being recorded?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, html5-audio, mediastream

I am using MediaStream Recording API to record audio in the browser, like this (courtesy https://github.com/bryanjenningz/record-audio):

```
      const recordAudio = () =>
        new Promise(async resolve => {

          // This wants to be secure. It will throw unless served from https:// or localhost.
          const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });

          const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
          let audioChunks = [];

          mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', event => {
            audioChunks.push(event.data);
            console.log("Got audioChunk!!", event.data.size, event.data.type);
      //      mediaRecorder.requestData()
          });

          const start = () => {
            audioChunks = [];
            mediaRecorder.start(1000); // milliseconds per recorded chunk
          };

          const stop = () =>
            new Promise(resolve => {
              mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', () => {
                const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/mpeg' });
                const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
                const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
                const play = () => audio.play();
                resolve({ audioChunks, audioBlob, audioUrl, play });
              });

              mediaRecorder.stop();
            });

          resolve({ start, stop });
        });
```

I would like to modify this code to start streaming to nodejs while it's still recording. I understand the header won't be complete until it finished the recording. I can either account for that on nodejs, or perhaps I can live with invalid headers, because I'll be feeding this into ffmpeg on nodejs anyway. How do I do this?

Comment: You can for each chunk create a buffer (Uint8Array) which you convert to String and encode base64 and send it to a POST endpoint on your server, which "glues" the chunks then back together to a big Binary. Something like this?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is when you start your recorder, start it like this [mediaRecorder.start(timeSlice)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/start#parameters), where `timeSlice` is the number of milliseconds the browser waits before emitting a `dataavailable` event with a blob of data.

Then, in your event handler for `dataavailable` you call the server:

```js
    mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', event => {

        myHTTPLibrary.post(event.data);

    });
```

That's the general solution. It's not possible to insert an example here, because a code sandbox can't ask you to use your webcam, but I've created one [here](https://magick.church/posts/stream-to-node/#demo). It simply sends your data to [Request Bin](https://requestbin.com), where you can watch the data stream in.

There are some other things you'll need to think about if you want to stitch the video or audio back together. The blog post touches on that.